# How do I distinguish a file or a folder in a drag and drop event in c#?

Tags: c#, file, drag-and-drop, directory

I have a form that you drag and drop files into and I was wondering how can I make the application know if the data is a file or a folder.

My first attempt was to look for a "." in the data but then some folders do have a . in them. I've also tried doing a File.Exists and a Directory.Exists condition but then it only searches on the current application path and not anywhere else.

Is there anyway I can somehow apply the .Exists in a specific directory or is there a way I can check what type of data is dragged into the form?

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Does your application retrieve the full path or the relative path? (Please give examples.) If it only retrieves the relative path, you will need to `Path.Combine` with the application path to get the full path.

Comment: Yes, rwong that's the problem I had. It wasn't getting the full path. The .Exists approach now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given the path as a string, you can use [System.IO.File.GetAttributes(string path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx) to get the [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) enum, and then check if the `FileAttributes.Directory` flag is set.

To check for a folder in .NET versions prior to .NET 4.0 you should do:

```
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(path);
bool isFolder = (attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
```

In newer versions you can use the `HasFlag` method to get the same result:

```
bool isFolder = File.GetAttributes(path).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);
```

Note also that [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) can provide various other flags about the file/folder, such as:

- `FileAttributes.Directory`: path represents a folder
- `FileAttributes.Hidden`: file is hidden
- `FileAttributes.Compressed`: file is compressed
- `FileAttributes.ReadOnly`: file is read-only
- `FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed`: excluded from indexing

etc.

Comment: I prefer: `bool isFolder = File.GetAttributes(file).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);`

Comment: +1 @Dan but keep in mind this is not available in older versions of the framework in which case the solution above is the way to go.

Comment: @TimothyP In that case, a little bit logic never hurt anyone. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Directory.Exists(path))
  // then it is a directory
else
  // then it is a file
```