# How to distinguish a file from a folder while uploading using drag and drop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

If a user tries to drag and drop a folder to my file uploader control for uploading it, then I need to show an error message to the user saying that only files can be uploaded. The problem is I couldn't distinguish a file from a folder.

One way I thought was to check for file type property of jQuery. Supposing that the name of the file is "test.txt", then file type would return "text/plain". For a normal folder name such as "TestFolder", file type would be blank and its file size would return 0. However if the folder name included an extension like "TestFolder.txt", then file type would return "text/plain".

So I could have checked for file type and file size but it would not work correctly for folder name like "TestFolder.txt". Could any one suggest me a good solution to fix this using jQuery or other methods?

Comment: Could you specify what "drag and drop" plugin are you using? (if any)

Comment: You might want to take note as well that IE has no FileAPI yet, so it might not give you a filesize for it, probably just a name.

Comment: Saw this and thought it might help you, they had the same problem: [How to distinguish a file or folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893787/how-do-i-distinguish-a-file-or-a-folder-in-a-drag-and-drop-event-in-c)

Comment: Have a look at:
http://hs2n.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/detecting-folders-in-html-drop-area/

Here is someone with the same issue who found a way to figure out....

Answer (score 3):

The ability to determine if a folder has been dropped is dependent on the user agent's support of the [Filesystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/).  If the user agent DOES support the Filesystem API (currently only Chrome 21+), you can make use of the `Entry` interface, which has two child interfaces: `DirectoryEntry` and `FileEntry`.  The interface itself has `isDirectory` and `isFile` functions.  Without support for this interface, there is no way to determine if dropped items are folders when examining the `DataTransfer` object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not going to allow folder to drag and drop, first check if it's folder or file, second only if it's not folder then check for file extension. But IE < 11 does not support file API to handle. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware the browser (And javascript inherently) doesn't have access to any file access methodologies for security purposes so you cannot check what the file actually is.

I have worked with this problem myself in the past and the best option I have found that works is to handle the file server-side, and return the error back to the page after upload has completed.

I would be happy to see better alternatives myself though.