# How do I support dragging and dropping a folder in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I would like to know how to Drag and Drop a folder and get its name. I already know how to do it with a file, but I'm not really sure how to modify it to be able to drag folders as well. Here's the code of the event that is triggered when a file is dropped:

```
private void checkedListBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        // NB: I'm only interested in the first file, even if there were
        // multiple files dropped
        string fileName = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I distinguish a file or a folder in a drag and drop event in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893787/how-do-i-distinguish-a-file-or-a-folder-in-a-drag-and-drop-event-in-c)

Comment: I have already googled. I'm not interested in basic drag and drop, but dropping a folder and getting its name, even if it's empty. EDIT: taking a look at sixlettervariables' link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could test if the path is a folder and in your [`DragEnter` handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx), conditionally change the `Effect`:

```
 void Target_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
     DragDropEffects effects = DragDropEffects.None;
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     {
         var path = ((string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
         if (Directory.Exists(path))
             effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
     }

     e.Effect = effects;
 }
```

Comment: I just wrote my own answer, but since you provided me the link I'll accept yours. Thanks! :)